# Como criar condicionais em read e write de arquivos de texto (python3)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, texto

Então, como eu poderia pegar um texto como esse por exemplo:

```
"testo<br>de<br>exemplo<br>"
```

e criar uma condicional (depois de dar o .open('arquivo.txt', 'r')) para cada vez que o programa encontrar o < br > ao ler o arquivo, pular uma linha (e talvez até apagar o < br > depois que pular a linha)? Obrigado desde já.

```
arquivo = open('arquivo.txt', 'w')

for line in arquivo:
    if #pedaçodaline == '<br':
        # deletar o <br>
        print('\n')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer o programa "pular" uma linha ao encontrar o `"<br>"` no texto, basta utilizar o método de string `replace` para realizar a substituição desse elemento pelo caractere especial `"\n"`.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
file = open("arquivo.txt", "w")
texto = file.read()

texto = texto.replace("<br>", "\n") # Substitui o "<br>" pelo caractere de quebra de linha
```

Para apagar este elemento do texto, basta utilizar o mesmo método só que agora passando um string vazia no segundo parâmetro.

```
texto = texto.replace("<br>", "")
```

Uma coisa bem interessante, é que não é necessário criar uma condicional para fazer isso já que, se o caractere existir na linha ele será substituído e se ele não existir, não irá acontecer nenhuma modificação na linha.

Seu código então ficaria assim:

```
arquivo = open('arquivo.txt', 'w')

for line in arquivo:
    line = line.replace("<br>", "")

    # Seu código...
```

Comment: Consegui aqui! Muito obrigado!